# While loop stops working but the process continues running in python

Tags: python, csv, urllib

I use a while loop in Python to download several pdf documents given by a csv file.
The code runs smoothly without any issue but the loop stops working after several loops (sometimes 100 other times 40 or 140).

Below is my code which is used:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import urllib
from urllib import request
import requests
import csv
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Linklist.csv', sep = ';') # can also index sheet by name or fetch all sheets

df.head() #get relevant columns
url_list = df['URL'].tolist() #column with links
name_list = df['Name'].tolist() #column with name
name_list_2 =df['Year'].to_list() #column with second identifier here a year for example

Year_date = []

for element in name_list_2:
    Year_date.append(str(element))


max_length = len(url_list)
i = 0

f = open('results.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)

while i <= max_length-1:

    response = requests.get(url_list[i])
    opener =      urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15')]
           
    if response.status_code != 200:
        i += 1
        a = str(response.status_code)
        write_a = (name_list[i], Year_date[i], a)
        writer.writerow(write_a)
        print(name_list[i]+' '+ Year_date[i]+ ' ' +a)
    else:
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        request.urlretrieve( url_list[i],'/targetpath/'+ name_list[i] + Year_date[i] + '.pdf') #.pdf if it is a pdf doc you want to download
        b = str(response.status_code)
        write_b = (name_list[i], Year_date[i], b)
        writer.writerow(write_b)
        print(name_list[i]+' '+ Year_date[i] + ' '+ b)
        i += 1

f.close()
```

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop? `for url, name, date in zip(url_list, name_list, Year_date):`

Comment: Perhaps you get blocked from the server hosting the PDF documents. You should pass in a [timeout parameter](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) to `requests.get()`

Comment: @Marx -- if your goal is to retry the request you shouldn't be incrementing at the end of the loop, if your goal is to always increment you should use a for loop. -- it also looks like you don't really need the dataframe at all; so I'd simply loop through the csv rows instead

Comment: @Barmar The second i is not correctly intended in the code displayed. That error is not present in the running code. Sorry for that, i edited it correctly. I use a while loop just because it felt more natural tbh, might write a version with for.

To add the list is 1100 Items long.

Comment: If you're incrementing `i` in both `if` and `else`, why don't you take it out and do it unconditionally?

Comment: What do you mean by "the loop stops working after several loops"? What does it do instead of querying the URL?

Comment: @barmar there is no reason behind the i. But thanks for the hint! When I’m running the code in Dataspell or in Jupyter Notebook the printing stops(which i added to monitor the process) and there are no new pdfs downloaded, even if I wait for an hour or more. Plus the process is still running (says the ides i mentioned and because the csv I create to track http errors is not closed via f.close())

Comment: Maybe you need to specify a timeout for `requests.get()`? It might be hanging if the server doesn't respond.

Comment: @barmer The timeout hint is the next thing I try, as it seems a good idea by you and ogdenkev. Let you know if it fixed the issue

Comment: @Barmar
The hin with the timeout was really good! I implemented it and it now runs smoothly! 
I put the working code inside my original post!

Answer (score 0):

The information by @barmar and @ogdenkev is correct I needed to integrate a Timeout component!
The working code looks like this now (just integrated the part which I changed):

```
DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 180

old_send = requests.Session.send

def new_send(*args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get("timeout", None) is None:
        kwargs["timeout"] = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
    return old_send(*args, **kwargs)

requests.Session.send = new_send

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15'}

while i <= max_length-1:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url_list[I], headers = headers)
        opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15')]
        if response.status_code != 200:
            a = str(response.status_code)
            write_a = (name_list[i], Year_date[i], a)
            writer.writerow(write_a)
            print(name_list[i]+' '+ Year_date[i]+ ' ' +a)
            print(i)
            i += 1

        else:
            urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
            request.urlretrieve( url_list[i],'/path/'+ name_list[i] + Year_date[i] + '.pdf') #.pdf if it is a pdf doc you want to download
            b = str(response.status_code)
            write_b = (name_list[i], Year_date[i], b)
            writer.writerow(write_b)
            print(name_list[i]+' '+ Year_date[i] + ' '+ b)
            print(i)
            i += 1
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        c = 'Timeout'
        write_a = (name_list[i], Year_date[i], c)
        writer.writerow(write_a)
        print(name_list[i]+' '+ Year_date[i]+ ' ' +c)
        print(i)
        i += 1

f.close()
```